# Embed editable Google Doc Spreadsheet in web page

Tags: django, embed, google-sheets

I am trying to embed a "live" spreadsheet in a django template via an iframe containing a Google Doc spreadsheet. I want the spreadsheet to be editable from the web page where it is embeded. I cut and paste the iframe markup from one of my Google Docs spreadsheet and put it into my web page.

```
<iframe width='800' height='700' frameborder='0' 
src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?
key=0AhfnV_dHuG5tdFFzdDRMMnRkWlVEbE9HZ1ZvUnFpcUE&
output=html&widget=true'></iframe>
```

This displays the spreadsheet and also reflect the changes in the spreadsheet but is not editable. How do I make it editable from the web page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that the "publish to web" in Google Docs gives you a non-editable version of the spreadsheet. (So this is not really a django problem.)

You will need to do "share", select in "Who has access" that "Anyone with a link" does, and select that Anyone with no sign-in can edit.
Then use the sharing link as the src= value.

Comment: Good solution, but of course even if you have to authenticate to see the embed page, that src url is still accessible by anyone if they have the link.

Is there a way to use the "share with everyone at organization X" link as your src and authenticate users so that you can prevent anyone from editing?

Comment: did we have a solution to @daveaseeman question above