# Problems while embedding an editable Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, iframe, embed, google-sheets

I'm trying to embed an editable google spreadsheet in a simple HTML page.
Most places on the web including [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877231/embed-editable-google-doc-spreadsheet-in-web-page), ask me to try fixing the URL. However this does not work for me for some reason.

```
<iframe width='300' height='500' frameborder='0' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap2hoxVM_haNdERKVlZDaGQxUTdJX0J3OEFaaURELUE&usp=sharing&single=true&range=A1%3AB36&output=html&widget=true&rm=minimal'></iframe>
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the embed code http://jsfiddle.net/NwWvd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's ok with code. Here is working code with my spreadsheet:

```
<iframe width='300' height='500' frameborder='0' src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1_E95obcIyHPRdblORhNqzbLRTz2Oo17TntFXXv7El14&usp=sharing&single=true&range=A1%3AB36&output=html&widget=true&rm=minimal'></iframe>
```

Problem is with sharing permission. Check this out.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. However I did find that '&output=html' was a culprit. Removing it made the spreadsheet bigger than the assigned range but it retained editability. Adding it reinforced the range but lost the editability.

Comment: Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_E95obcIyHPRdblORhNqzbLRTz2Oo17TntF…El14/htmlembed?usp=sharing&single=true&range=A1:B36&widget=true&rm=minimal' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.