# Integrate Into Office 365 / Google Docs as part of website solution

Tags: php, google-docs-api, office365-apps

we have a web based software package which as part of its remit, handles viewing / editing word files (mainly, sometimes pdfs - although I know editing these isn't going to work).

Currently the client runs it in a standard environment, so we can use MS Word in order to handle updates to those files. However, they're looking to move it into 'the cloud', so we ideally need a cloud based solution to edit the files.

I appreciate we'd probably need to move the files into Google Drive or Azure from the website server in order for the respective systems to open the file, but is it possible to embed Word 365 or Google Docs into a webpage (i.e an iFrame) within our solution on our server, but Word/Docs drags the file from Azure / Google and opens it in the browser.

Comment: This other question may help you embedding Google docs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877231/embed-editable-google-doc-spreadsheet-in-web-page

Comment: Cheers Gerarado, its close. However since asking the question, I've found out that the clients we're talking to all have 365 accounts, so its going to have to be a 365 solution.